# URL RewriteCond for dynamics urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here is my dynamic url

http://www.125books.com/search-bk?s=20&kw=thermodynamics&ser=y

i want it to  rewrite this url  and kw parameter at the end,so that it may look like this

http://www.125books.com/search-bk/20/y/thermodynamics

kindly help me how to set RewriteCond  in .htaccess file and how to set Rewrite Rule

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(search-bk(?:\.php)?)\?s=([^&]*)&kw=([^&]*)&ser=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%4/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(search-bk)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?s=$2&kw=$4&ser=$3 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This worked in my testing. What is location of above .htaccess and are there other rules. Provide all details and post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: sir i have placed my htaacess file in the answer

Comment: OK place this updated rule just before 2nd rule that does internal forward of php files.

Comment: sir kindly write RewriteCond to capture query strings and then rewrite rule

Comment: sir this prodeuce results like  www.125books.com/search-bk///y instead of www.125books.com/search-bk/20/thermo/y  . it is not showing the value of "s" and i want to show keyword "kw" value at the last...kindly help me sir

Comment: sir in updated code page does not move to next page it remains on the same page like www.125books.com/search-bk ... it does not move to next pagination page like www.125books.com/search-bk/20/n/

Comment: sir it does not show the value of "S" and "kw" it is showing only value of "ser"  ...kindly make it it show value of "kw" at the end so that when user just go through pagination it show some thing like this  www.125books.com/search-bk/20/n/     and if user search something it show like this www.125books.com/search-bk/20/y/somestring/     where 20 is page number it may be 5,10,15 ...or higher something.  and somestring is the search string wharever user search by typing in the search bar..  sir kindly help me

Comment: It is getting to understand what your problem is. What is location of above .htaccess? Just test with single URL first i.e. `http://www.125books.com/search-bk?s=20&kw=thermodynamics&ser=y`

Comment: sir i want to show kw value at the end . like  http://www.125books.com/search-bk/20/y/thermodynamics

Comment: sir we are not moving to next page like  125books.com/search-bk/25/y/thermodynamics  .it does not capture the value of "kw=thermodyanmics" and "s=20"  it shows the result only like  125books.com/search-bk///y  which means value of "s" which 20 and "kw" which is thermodynamics is missing or it is not capturing that values

Comment: With my rule it will first redirect `http://www.125books.com/search-bk?s=20&kw=thermodynamics&ser=y` to http://www.125books.com/search-bk/20/y/thermodynamics` is it not happening for you? If not test in a different browser to avoid caching.

Comment: sir "s" and "kw" values are dynamics and page numbers and user search query may change ,, so it shoud capture "kw" value and "s" values

Comment: Start answering my question first. When you enter `http://www.125books.com/search-bk?s=20&kw=thermodynamics&ser=y` in your browser does it redirect to `http://www.125books.com/search-bk/20/y/thermodynamics` OR not?

Comment: sir kindly make it to prvious state when it ws giving result like   www.125books.com/search-bk///y    then capture only s and kw values ,,kindly do this sir please

Comment: no sir it redirect to http://www.125books.com/search-bk which is my search page ...it always remain there rather we search something or not, rather we go to next page. it shows the same results. even when we click on the next page .. kindly help me.

Comment: In which directory did you place above .htaccess? Place your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: sir it is exactly as above as your updated answer..and .htaccess file is on the root

Comment: ok in that case I cant guess what's wrong on your site since everything worked in my testing.